# Char Device Driver with Port Expansion using MCP23017

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver

I am new to Linux Kernel Development and I want to implement a Char device driver which handles Port expansion using a MCP23017 with a RaspberryPi (Raspbian Wheezy) using C.

A control for port expansion (MCP23017) is required. A less of a driver in the true sense, but more with porting functions in a driver.
 
The module is addressed via I2C. I need to implement the following functions in the driver:

· Configuration of the I2C address

· Configuration of the IOs

· Configuration of Pull-Ups

· Configuration of interrupts

· Read / write the IOs

It is important that up to 8 modules can be opened/operated simultaneously (8 is the max. possible number of addresses of the block).

I have seen a number of examples in the internet and implemented a simple char device driver with `init`, `open`, `read` and `write` functions and also tested I2C operations for MCP23017. I have got a brief idea about a device driver but don't know how to further implement the functions.

I would like to know/clarified about the following:

1. How does the `dev_open` work? How can I try to open a device through a linux command and check if the device is opened/ the number of times the device is opened through `dmesg` command?
2. I want 8 different modules to be opened simultaneously using the device driver and the Configuration of the MCP23017 IOs, Pullups and Interrupts.  How is it done?

Errors:

```
/home/pi/i2c_gpio/mcp23017.c: In function ‘mcp23s08_direction_input’:
/home/pi/i2c_gpio/mcp23017.c:269:9: error: implicit declaration of function      
‘gpiochip_get_data’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
struct mcp23s08 *mcp = gpiochip_get_data(chip);      

/home/pi/i2c_gpio/mcp23017.c: In function ‘mcp23s08_probe_one’:
/home/pi/i2c_gpio/mcp23017.c:615:11: error: ‘struct gpio_chip’ has no         
member  named ‘parent’
mcp->chip.parent = dev;                  

/home/pi/i2c_gpio/mcp23017.c:681:2: error: implicit declaration of  
function ‘gpiochip_add_data’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
status = gpiochip_add_data(&mcp->chip, mcp);
^
```

Comment: There has already been a driver for this since at least 3.9.

Comment: To complement @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams's comment, [here is the existing driver implementation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/gpio/gpio-mcp23s08.c).

Comment: Thank you. I used the above mentioned driver implementation. But I get the following errors (edited the question with errors) .

Comment: You're trying to build it in the context of a kernel makefile, right?

Comment: Yes. With a kernel makefile

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find the function `gpiochip_get_data` and `gpiochip_add_data` in any of the libraries. I am using RPi 4.4.13-v7+. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: @unwind Does the driver implementation you mentioned support 8 chips at a time?

Comment: @AlexKrish, you have to build the driver in the kernel environment. The driver support as many instances as you have described in your device tree.